# spatial join by geometry and time in python(geopandas)

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-query

I'm tryihng to merge 2 geodataframes.(let's say 'df_a' and 'df_b')
and I want to join those 2 dfs by time and geometry

In case of 'df_a' it's geometry is 'multipolygon'.

| time | feature 1 | ... | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '2017-01-01' | 10 | ... | MULTIPOLYGON (((-35.12334 3.12648, -35.12334 2... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| '2020-12-31' | 4 | ... | MULTIPOLYGON (((-18.12334 21.11820, -18.12334 ... |

In case of 'df_b' it's geometry is 'point'.

| time | feature 2 | ... | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '2017-08-01' | 1 | ... | POINT (-35.25000 3.00000) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| '2020-10-15' | 7 | ... | POINT (-34.25000 3.00000) |

As you may recognized, both data frames' time variation is different.
Also, 'df_a' is multipolygon type, and 'df_b' has the point type

And I wonder how to join those 2 dfs by the criteria of 'time' and 'geometry' using geopandas in Python?

FYI

1. both data frame has same WGS(EPSG:4326)
2. df_a's time variation is wider
3. every points of 'df_b' are in multipolygon of 'df_a'
4. some of multipolygons may not contains any points

And, as long as I know, there is no parms that can designate criteria (just like pandas merge)
The only thing that I know about the spatial join by the geopandas is

```
gpd.sjoin(df_a, df_b, how='left', predicate='intersects')
```

is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the rows after performing `sjoin()`:

```
gpd.sjoin(df_a, df_b, how="left", predicate="intersects").loc[
    lambda d: d["time_left"].eq(d["time_right"])
]
```

#### MWE for generating data sets

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# synthesize some geodataframes matching structure in question
df_a = (
    pd.merge(
        pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-jan-2017", "31-dec-2020", freq="15D"), name="time"),
        gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"index": "feature 1"})
        .drop(columns=["name"]),
        how="cross",
    )
    .sample(100)
    .sort_values(["time", "feature 1"])
)
df_a = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_a)

df_b = (
    pd.merge(
        pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-jan-2017", "31-dec-2020", freq="15D"), name="time"),
        gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"index": "feature 2"})
        .drop(columns=["name", "pop_est", "continent", "gdp_md_est"]),
        how="cross",
    )
    # .sample(50)
    .sort_values(["time", "feature 2"])
)
df_b = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_b)
```

#### output

|  | time_left | feature 1 | geometry | index_right | time_right | feature 2 | iso_a3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 105 | POINT (-88.76707299981655 17.252033507246892) | 39 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 39 | BLZ |
| 120 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 120 | POINT (18.383001666953305 43.850022398954934) | 170 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 170 | BIH |
| 283 | 2017-01-16 00:00:00 | 81 | POINT (-89.2049870794599 13.711947505494038) | 214 | 2017-01-16 00:00:00 | 37 | SLV |
| 527 | 2017-01-31 00:00:00 | 123 | POINT (44.06531001666542 9.56002239881775) | 521 | 2017-01-31 00:00:00 | 167 | -99 |
| 600 | 2017-01-31 00:00:00 | 196 | POINT (-74.08528981377441 4.598369421147822) | 386 | 2017-01-31 00:00:00 | 32 | COL |
| 861 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 | 53 | POINT (-86.27043751890119 12.154962438756115) | 743 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 | 35 | NIC |
| 1001 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 | 193 | POINT (116.38633982565943 39.93083808990906) | 847 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 | 139 | CHN |
| 1161 | 2017-03-17 00:00:00 | 151 | POINT (-69.90203094331503 18.472018713195382) | 902 | 2017-03-17 00:00:00 | 17 | DOM |
| 1451 | 2017-04-16 00:00:00 | 37 | POINT (10.179678099212026 36.80277813623144) | 1320 | 2017-04-16 00:00:00 | 81 | TUN |
| 1589 | 2017-04-16 00:00:00 | 175 | POINT (13.399602764700546 52.523764522251156) | 1360 | 2017-04-16 00:00:00 | 121 | DEU |

Comment: Thank you for your kinder comment.

The code works very well, but unfortunately, it's not suitable for my data.

Your code just conducts a merge 2 data frames by the spatial criteria as just as normal spatial join and then finds the same 'time' value from the result of the 'sjoin'.

What I was trying to do was merge two data frames by the criteria of 'time' and 'geometry' at the same time. 

Which means, it needs to consider 'time' when the 'sjoin' finds a spatial value that meets the criteria. (It may be the problem of my poor English skill)

Comment: * merge two data frames by the criteria of 'time' and 'geometry' * from a relation / logic algebra point of view doing one by the other fulfils the **and** requirement.  i.e. it will find all rows that meet spatial criteria then remove ones that do not meet time criteria.  that is fully equivalent to what you have stated

Comment: I thought your code didn't work for my dataset, but actually, it works very well as much as I wanted.

FYI, I should've asked a question with more detail.

While join two data by the geometry and time, I didn't want to drop any data from the data that included polygon. (What I want was a result of 'left join' ).
But when I ask you a question, there was no such comment of that and your answer to my first question was a perfectly correct answer.

Anyway, this is my fault for not asking the right questions, and your code made me study and grow more. Thank you for your kind explanation.

Comment: happy it worked - learning is always continuous.  it's often the case with learning you refactor a question you started with.  IMHO this is a good thing, especially if you are then able to answer your refactored question :-)